# Can't access json from url d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to access the JSON data from an URL to create a chart in D3.

```
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwy56QiQwyfkkaLFWZ33QHVieAHhtLJYNa_AzKcCBr-J7Catgv2/exec?id=1vQsWQPUET20KcgeRKgs5NOOBngqLeUuNTHI1bWi5Et8&sheet=Sheet1";

d3.json(url, function (json) {
  console.log(json[0]);
});
```

My JSON data loooks like

```
{
  "Sheet1" : [{
      "time" : 0,
      "Date" : "2016-08-09T23:00:00.000Z",
      "Impressions" : 18275,
      "Cost" : 66.87,
      "Actions:_link_clicks" : 110,
      "Offsite_conversions" : 8,
      "Actions:_video_views" : 2071,
      "Reach" : 17692,
      "Clicks" : 230,
      "Call-to-action_clicks" : 0,
      "Click-through_rate_(CTR)" : 1.26,
      "Video_complete_views" : 549,
      "Actions:_post_engagements" : 2210,
      "Actions:_post_reactions" : 24,
      "Actions:_posts" : 2
    }, {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

First I just wanted to test and print the data in the console. But nothing is getting printed in the console.

Am I doing something wrong?

I added this in the header with script tags to reference d3.js:

```
"https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned `JSON` data is not an array, hence array indexing it, `[0]` returns `undefined`.  The `JSON` data does though have a property of `Sheet1` which in an array, perhaps you meant:

```
console.log(json.Sheet1[0])
```